# java program doubt

Tags: java

i have created a input form using Netbeans IDE containing a button and a Textarea.
if i click a button it should call output.java program where the main part of execution resides and it should display the output in the TextArea created in the input.java.
Am not getting the output in TextArea..the reason is my output.java program cudnt identify the textarea.
but am getting output in window output console.please help me overcome this problem.thanks in advance

Comment: Is that really the most descriptive title you could come up with?

Comment: How do you "call output.java program"? Invoking its `main()`? `Process exec`? Can you modify `output.java` to use an arbitrary `PrintStream` or is it hardcoded to `System.out`? Give us more details.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're [doing it all wrong](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016). The textarea is in a different process so you need to capture the output of the other program yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a reference of the JTextarea in question to the output.java as a Constructor or method argument.